# Failed to Access "Table Column' in WebServices using PHP in YII Controller?

Tags: php, web-services, yii

Here is my module controller in which one foreign is working fine while failed to get result from Foreign key....

```
<?php

    class UserCourseController extends Controller
    {
        public function actionIndex()
        {
        $this->render('index');
        } 
         public function actionGetUserCourse()
                {
                    if(isset($_POST['user_id']) && !empty($_POST['user_id']))
                    {
                         $response = array();
                         $userId = $_POST['user_id'];

                        $courseRecord = UserCourseModelNew::model()->findAll('user_id=:userId',array(':userId'=>$userId));

                        if($courseRecord){
                        foreach($courseRecord as $rec){
                           $rec->user_id=$rec->user->user_name;
                          $rec->course_id=$rec->course->course_name;   
                          }
                          $response['status'] = true;
                          $response['message']="Record Found";
                          $response['user_course']=$courseRecord;

                  }
                  else {
                         $response['status'] = false;
                         $response['message']="Record not Found";

                  }
                         echo CJSON::encode($response);

                    }
         else {
             echo "error found";
         }
                }

        }
```

There are two same lines but one is working fine while another one is throwing errors:

```
    $rec->user_id=$rec->user->user_name;
    $rec->course_id=$rec->course->course_name;
```

This line is creating problem and giving me error when i comment first line then no error i testing in form here is the error list while there is no Users.php class in my whole project so how this error coming**ERROR:**

```
 PHP warning

include(Users.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.8.r3324\framework\YiiBase.php(421)

409                         {
410                             include($classFile);
411                             if(YII_DEBUG && basename(realpath($classFile))!==$className.'.php')
412                                 throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','Class name "{class}" does not match class file "{file}".', array(
413                                     '{class}'=>$className,
414                                     '{file}'=>$classFile,
415                                 )));
416                             break;
417                         }
418                     }
419                 }
420                 else
421                     include($className.'.php');
422             }
423             else  // class name with namespace in PHP 5.3
424             {
425                 $namespace=str_replace('\\','.',ltrim($className,'\\'));
426                 if(($path=self::getPathOfAlias($namespace))!==false)
427                     include($path.'.php');
428                 else
429                     return false;
430             }
431             return class_exists($className,false) || interface_exists($className,false);
432         }
433         return true;
Stack Trace
#0  
+  C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.8.r3324\framework\YiiBase.php(421): YiiBase::autoload()
#1  
 unknown(0): YiiBase::autoload("Users")
#2  
+  C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.8.r3324\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(386): spl_autoload_call("Users")
#3  
+  C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.8.r3324\framework\db\ar\CActiveFinder.php(215): CActiveRecord::model("Users")
#4  
+  C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.8.r3324\framework\db\ar\CActiveFinder.php(48): CActiveFinder->buildJoinTree(CJoinElement, "user")
#5  
+  C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.8.r3324\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(271): CActiveFinder->__construct(UserCourseModelNew, "user")
#6  
–  C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.8.r3324\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(141): CActiveRecord->getRelated("user")
136         elseif(isset($this->getMetaData()->columns[$name]))
137             return null;
138         elseif(isset($this->_related[$name]))
139             return $this->_related[$name];
140         elseif(isset($this->getMetaData()->relations[$name]))
141             return $this->getRelated($name);
142         else
143             return parent::__get($name);
144     }
145 
146     /**
#7  
–  C:\wamp\www\examapp\protected\modules\services\controllers\UserCourseController.php(52): CActiveRecord->__get("user")
47      echo "<PRE>";
48     // echo $rec->user->id; exit();
49 print_r($courseRecord);                    
50 //print_r("$rec:"+$rec->course->course_name);      
51                    
52                   $rec->user_id=$rec->user->id;
53                   $rec->course_id=$rec->course->course_name;   
54                   
55                   
56                 }
57                   $response['status'] = true;
#8  
–  C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.8.r3324\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php(49): UserCourseController->actionGetUserCourse()
44         $controller=$this->getController();
45         $method=new ReflectionMethod($controller, $methodName);
46         if($method->getNumberOfParameters()>0)
47             return $this->runWithParamsInternal($controller, $method, $params);
48         else
49             return $controller->$methodName();
50     }
51 
52 }
#9  
–  C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.8.r3324\framework\web\CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(array())
303     {
304         $priorAction=$this->_action;
305         $this->_action=$action;
306         if($this->beforeAction($action))
307         {
308             if($action->runWithParams($this->getActionParams())===false)
309                 $this->invalidActionParams($action);
310             else
311                 $this->afterAction($action);
312         }
313         $this->_action=$priorAction;
#10 
+  C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.8.r3324\framework\web\CController.php(286): CController->runAction(CInlineAction)
#11 
+  C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.8.r3324\framework\web\CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(CInlineAction, array())
#12 
+  C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.8.r3324\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run("GetUserCourse")
#13 
+  C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.8.r3324\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController("services/UserCourse/GetUserCourse")
#14 
+  C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.8.r3324\framework\base\CApplication.php(169): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#15 
–  C:\wamp\www\examapp\index.php(13): CApplication->run()
08 defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
09 // specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
10 defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);
11 
12 require_once($yii);
13 Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

**UsersCourseModelNew.php:**

```
 <?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user_course".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'user_course':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property integer $course_id
 * @property string $status
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property Course $course
 * @property Users $user
 */

    class UserCourseModelNew extends CActiveRecord
    {
        public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
        {
            return parent::model($className);
        }
        public function tableName()
        {
            return 'user_course';
        }
        public function rules()
        {

            return array(
                array('user_id, course_id', 'required'),
                array('user_id, course_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
                array('status', 'length', 'max'=>8),
                array('id, user_id, course_id, status', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
            );
        }
        public function relations()
        {
            // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
            // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
            return array(
                'course' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Course', 'course_id'),
                'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'user_id'),
            );
        }
        public function attributeLabels()
        {
            return array(
                'id' => 'ID',
                'user_id' => 'User',
                'course_id' => 'Course',
                'status' => 'Status',
            );
        }
        public function search()
        {
            $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

            $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
            $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);
            $criteria->compare('course_id',$this->course_id);
            $criteria->compare('status',$this->status,true);

            return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
            ));
        }
    }
```

**Edit: UsersModel.php**

```
    <?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "users".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'users':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $user_name
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $date_created
 * @property string $date_modified
 * @property string $user_type
 * @property string $mobile_no
 * @property integer $required
 * @property integer $role_id
 * @property string $status
 * @property string $first_name
 * @property string $last_name
 * @property string $gender
 * @property string $religon
 * @property string $phone_no
 * @property string $email
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property QuestionBank[] $questionBanks
 * @property QuestionReplyAnswer[] $questionReplyAnswers
 * @property UserCourse[] $userCourses
 * @property UserSchedule[] $userSchedules
 * @property Role $role
 */
class UsersModel extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return UsersModel the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('user_name, password, date_created, date_modified, user_type, mobile_no', 'required'),
            array('required, role_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('user_type', 'length', 'max'=>7),
            array('status', 'length', 'max'=>8),
            array('first_name, last_name', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            array('gender', 'length', 'max'=>6),
            array('religon', 'length', 'max'=>10),
            array('phone_no, email', 'safe'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, user_name, password, date_created, date_modified, user_type, mobile_no, required, role_id, status, first_name, last_name, gender, religon, phone_no, email', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'questionBanks' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'QuestionBank', 'user_id'),
            'questionReplyAnswers' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'QuestionReplyAnswer', 'user_id'),
            'userCourses' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserCourse', 'user_id'),
            'userSchedules' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserSchedule', 'user_id'),
            'role' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Role', 'role_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'user_name' => 'User Name',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'date_created' => 'Date Created',
            'date_modified' => 'Date Modified',
            'user_type' => 'User Type',
            'mobile_no' => 'Mobile No',
            'required' => 'Required',
            'role_id' => 'Role',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'first_name' => 'First Name',
            'last_name' => 'Last Name',
            'gender' => 'Gender',
            'religon' => 'Religon',
            'phone_no' => 'Phone No',
            'email' => 'Email',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('user_name',$this->user_name,true);
        $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
        $criteria->compare('date_created',$this->date_created,true);
        $criteria->compare('date_modified',$this->date_modified,true);
        $criteria->compare('user_type',$this->user_type,true);
        $criteria->compare('mobile_no',$this->mobile_no,true);
        $criteria->compare('required',$this->required);
        $criteria->compare('role_id',$this->role_id);
        $criteria->compare('status',$this->status,true);
        $criteria->compare('first_name',$this->first_name,true);
        $criteria->compare('last_name',$this->last_name,true);
        $criteria->compare('gender',$this->gender,true);
        $criteria->compare('religon',$this->religon,true);
        $criteria->compare('phone_no',$this->phone_no,true);
        $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: check the `relations` of the `UserCourseModelNew` activerecord class... I'm sure you'd find a reference to a 'Users' model in there...

Comment: can you add your model code also

Comment: @ragingprodigy   public function relations()
 {
  // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
  // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
  return array(
   'course' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Course', 'course_id'),
   'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'user_id'),
  );
 }

Comment: this is the relation there is no Users model there

Comment: @kumar_v can u please check now i have added model code also its wasted my whole day and still i am failed to correct this pls check it

Comment: @user3233280 what is the class name of user model? and its filename also.

Comment: @kumar_v   model name of users table is "UserModel"

Comment: did you import all model in your code?

Comment: yes i have import all models

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47936/discussion-between-user3233280-and-kumar-v)